# How to count observation per time interval in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd


dict = {
    "id": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "start_time": [
        "2022-08-30 08:00:02",
        "2022-08-30 08:03:07",
        "2022-08-30 08:06:52",
        "2022-08-30 08:20:02",
        "2022-08-30 08:20:45",
    ],

    "end_time": [
        "2022-08-30 08:00:02",
        "2022-08-30 08:05:12",
        "2022-08-30 08:06:52",
        "2022-08-30 08:20:27",
        "2022-08-30 08:22:27",
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

I would like to count number of `id` per 5 minutes intervals. Starting from `2022-08-30 08:00:01` ending in `2022-08-30 08:25:00`

```py
new_dict = {
    "interval start": [
        "2022-08-30 08:00:01",
        "2022-08-30 08:05:01",
        "2022-08-30 08:10:00",
        "2022-08-30 08:15:01",
        "2022-08-30 08:20:01",
    ],

    "interval_end": [
        "2022-08-30 08:05:00",
        "2022-08-30 08:10:00",
        "2022-08-30 08:15:00",
        "2022-08-30 08:20:00",
        "2022-08-30 08:25:00",
    ],

    "count": [2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
}

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
```

How can I do it please?

Comment: can the span from `start_time` to `end_time` be longer than the interval length of 5 min?

Comment: @Stef yes. thats the one of the problems I have here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible use input data from [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73538538/2901002) use:

```
dict_df = {
    "id": [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    "time": [
        "2022-08-30 08:00:02",
        "2022-08-30 08:03:07",
        "2022-08-30 08:05:12",
        "2022-08-30 08:06:52",
        "2022-08-30 08:00:02",
        "2022-08-30 08:00:27",
        "2022-08-30 08:20:45",
        "2022-08-30 08:22:27",
    ],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min', key='time'))['id'].nunique().reset_index(name='count')
df = df.rename(columns={'time':'interval start'})
df.insert(1, 'interval end', df['interval start'] + pd.Timedelta('5Min'))
print (df)
       interval start        interval end  count
0 2022-08-30 08:00:00 2022-08-30 08:05:00      3
1 2022-08-30 08:05:00 2022-08-30 08:10:00      1
2 2022-08-30 08:10:00 2022-08-30 08:15:00      0
3 2022-08-30 08:15:00 2022-08-30 08:20:00      0
4 2022-08-30 08:20:00 2022-08-30 08:25:00      1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this makes something different. "2022-08-30 13:00:45" and "2022-08-30 13:02:27" is the same id, so it should be count = 1

Comment: @vojtam - I add `id` for count, how should looks expected ouput from this sample data?

Comment: I can't follow: neither the input nor the output of your answer correspond to the OP? Why do you group by `id`?

Comment: @jezrael id stands for employee. The problem is that in "2022-08-30 13:00:45" and "2022-08-30 13:02:27" is working only employee with id = 3. So the count should be 1. I need it from the intervals as we solved in the previous solution. I hope I make it clear, thanks for help

Comment: @vojtam - why in ouput are not `id` column?

Comment: @jezrael becuase I don`t need it. I just want to know how many ids belong to the interval, is it clear or should I explain it in the answer more in details?

Comment: @vojtam - So need count number of unique `id` per intervals? I change data in sample.